# Extracting part of an element in a python dictionary

Tags: python, extract

I'm trying to extract only the key of an element in my dictionary but I can only figure out how to append the value.

this is my dictionary:

```
{"Java": 10, "Ruby": 80, "Python": 65}
```

I want the output to be the languages with a grade higher than 60. In this case

```
"Ruby", "Python"
```

This is my code but with the `append()` function, I can only extract the grade.

```
def my_languages(results):
    output = [] 

    for i in results:
        if results[i] >= 60:
            output.append(results[i])
    return output
```

Thank you all in advance

Comment: That is not a list

Comment: The standard way to iterate over key:value pairs in python dictionaries is by using `dict.items()` . `for k, v in results.items():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we traverse the dictionary, the key of the dictionary is index, that is, I, so you need append to be “i”.

```
def my_languages(results):
    output = [] 
    for i in results:
        if results[i] >= 60:
            output.append(i)
    return output
```

Comment: ah yes thank you i didnt see that now is there also a quick way to sort the languages via how high the grade is?

Comment: @HiighQ Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/16177247) help?

Comment: I believe alec_djinn's answer is the more standard way of iterating over a dict's keys and values. From quiet_penguin's comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/16177247), accessing the dict like that causes the key to be hashed again.

Comment: you can sort the dict by its value, and find the first position of language:grade dict which value meet the situation , and use "output list" collect left items.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic Python, please check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict.items) and [some examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm) online

```
def my_languages(results):
    output = [] 
    for lang, grade in results.items():
        if grade >= 60:
            output.append(lang)
    return output
```